# Как отправить любые данные не из формы с помощью Ajax на почту?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, email

я сверстал и запрограммировал калькулятор с разными услугами, у каждой услуги свои данные для отправки. Если честно, еще никогда с php не сталкивался, да и ajax почти не знаю.

Суть такая, три услуги в виде табов, человек выбирает услугу, далее вводит и выбирает данные, чтоб узнать стоимость. Вот пример одной и услуг, но наткнулся на проблему. В одной из услуг есть такие данные, и я не знаю, как их отправить. Как отправить label выбранной радиокнопки или чекбокса?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        $('#my_send3').click(function() {

            if ($('#workSpace').prop('checked')) {


                $.post (
                'post.php', // адрес обработчика

                {
                    'Имя: ':
                    $('#call-name').val(),
                    'Телефон: ':
                    $('#call-tel').val(),
                    'Услуга':
                    'Рабочий проект',
                    'Тип объекта: ':
                    $('#workProject .calculator-select__choose').text(),
                    'Площадь: ':
                    $('#scale-budget_input').val().replace(' кв. м', '') + ' кв. м'
                },

                function(msg) {
                    $('.call-me__wrap').hide()
                    $('.call-me__complete').show()
                    }

                )
            
            return false;
            } else if ($('#designVisual').prop('checked')) {


                $.post (
                'post.php', // адрес обработчика

                {
                    'Имя: ':
                    $('#call-name').val(),
                    'Телефон: ':
                    $('#call-tel').val(),
                    'Услуга':
                    'Дизайн и визуализация',
                    'Тип объекта: ':
                    $('#visualAndDesign .calculator-select__choose').text(),
                    'Площадь: ':
                    $('#scale-building_input').val().replace(' кв. м', '') + ' кв. м'
                },

                function(msg) {
                    $('.call-me__wrap').hide()
                    $('.call-me__complete').show()
                    }

                )



            } else if ($('#building').prop('checked')) {

                $.post (
                'post.php', // адрес обработчика

                {
                    'Имя: ':
                    $('#call-name').val(),
                    'Телефон: ':
                    $('#call-tel').val(),
                    'Услуга':
                    'Строительство',
                    'Тип объекта: ':
                    $('#building .calculator-select__choose').text(),
                    'Площадь: ':
                    $('#scale-building_input').val().replace(' кв. м', '') + ' кв. м',
                    'Количество комнат':
                    $('.room-field').val(),
                    'Высота потолка':
                    $('.height-ceiling').val()
                },

                function(msg) {
                    $('.call-me__wrap').hide()
                    $('.call-me__complete').show()
                    }

                )

            }

        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знание не смертельно. Если есть API то в большинстве случаев есть и [документация](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)
в общем случае на jQuery это

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

а в частном

```
$.post( url: url,
      data: data,
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType)
```

data - это обьект. У Вас в нем есть не большие проблемы по типу

```
 'Площадь: ':
```

Думаю двоеточие лишнее посмотрите на свои оставшиеся поля.

По поводу Label Text

```
$(Нужный Вам чекбокс).next('label').text();
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как добавить только те чекбоксы в отправку, которые выбраны?

Comment: $('checkbox:checked') так

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/